# Why would HTML and CSS be required for .NET development?

Tags: .net, html, css, information

On a job application, part of the job description is "...needs to know HTML and CSS as some .NET is required...".  What does this mean?

I thought HTML is a programming language, CSS is a way to format HTML, and .NET is just a runtime framework that is not something you really "know".  Can someone please explain what this means to me?

Comment: it means that the person who wrote the description is either ignorant, or a bad typist who meant to write "and" instead of "ans"

Comment: I don't know where you are based, but in the UK, ".Net developer" is often used by (technically ignorant) recruiters when they actually mean "ASP.Net developer"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML is a design and layout language, not a programming language.  Is't almost always paired with JavaScript, which is a programming language.

.NET is a catchall name for a number of Microsoft technologies, among them C#, Visual Basic, CLR, and a number of frameworks.  It *is* a development mindset and languages that you have to know in order to be "a .NET developer".

Although it can be used for desktop applications, .NET is heavily used for web development; in that case you do need to know HTML, CSS and a few other things to complete any project.